i3wm i3lock with 2 monitors - resume from suspend only brings up main monitor
Setup
lenovo x1 carbon gen 10
2nd monitor linked through hdmi cable
ubuntu 22.04, i3wm, i3lock, i3lock-fancy
What's wrong
After resuming from suspend, the 2nd monitor is blank, not receiving any signal from the HDMI, although xrandr --listmonitors shows both the main and the hdmi connected one. Running xrandr --auto does nothing as well. The only workaround is to open the 2nd monitor, then resume suspend.
When using the ubuntu desktop enviroment the suspend/resume works without problem, so i'm suspecting it's from either i3wm or i3lock. Any ideas to solve this, please?
